# Shell script variables I saw but not sure what they mean

Tags: shell, parameters

My question is: What is v1,v2,v3,v4 and v5 in the below function?
They look like input parameters but I am not really sure what they are for. Can anyone explain it in a bit detail of what they do?

```
#!/bin/sh
compile()
{
v1="$1*z*"
v2=${2:-"$1*"}
v3=${3:-"$1*/"}
v4=${4:-"."}
v5=${5:-"."}

some other command and cd in here 

}
compile libpng
compile icu "" "" source build
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` etc. are the arguments to the function.

And, from the `bash(1)` man page, **EXPANSION** section, **Parameter Expansion** subsection:

> ```
>    ${parameter:-word}
>           Use  Default  Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expan‐
>           sion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of  parameter
>           is substituted.
> ```

Comment: I think it prepares name globbing in v1: if you do `eval echo $v1`, it will expand `$1*z*`, so that you get $1.bz, $1.tar.gz, and so on. If in the rest of the code some command extract from archive file, $v1 will expand itself with all archive. Just a supposition...